# Unable to run flask application as a service with systemd on Centos 7 server

Tags: python, flask, centos7, gunicorn, systemd

I'm able to run flask app within virtualenv `/web_services/flask_api/flask_api` like this:

`gunicorn --workers=4 --bind=localhost:8000 --log-level=error app:app`

But, when I try to run it as a service it's not working. Here's a post that I followed to create a `.service` config file:

https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/running-a-flask-application-as-a-service-with-systemd

Here's how my `web_service.service` file looks like:

```
[Unit]
Description=Sample web service
After=network.target 

[Service]
User=aaa.bbb
WorkingDirectory=/web_services/flask_api/flask_api
ExecStart=/web_services/flask_api/flask_api/bin/gunicorn --workers=4 --bind=localhost:8000 --log-level=error web_service:app
Restart=always 

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After saving this file I did:

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl start web_service
$ sudo systemctl enable web_service
```

`systemctl | grep running` is not displaying this api.

While checking status of this service, I'm getting this:

```
sudo systemctl status web_service
● web_service.service - Sample web service  
 Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/web_service.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)   
 Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Mon 2020-06-01 16:15:15 EDT; 13s ago 
 Process: 1016 ExecStart=/web_services/flask_api/flask_api/bin/gunicorn --workers=4 --bind=localhost:8000 --log-level=error web_service:app (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1016 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

Don't know what I'm missing here or doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: 1) You can check additional logs with `journalctl -e -u web_service`, the error message might help you. 2) As far as I remember I had the most trouble with the virtualenv, but I also heard that for "normal" virtual environments it should work as done in the article by just calling gunicorn from the virtual environment. I have working services (systemd and supervisord) that switch to the virtual env with `environment=PATH=.../env/bin:%(ENV_PATH)s"` and `command=bash -c ".../env/bin/activate && gunicorn ...`. But it feels totally dirty, so it's not worth an answer :)

Comment: Thanks so much, by looking at logs I could figure out what's going wrong. It got fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got solved by changing:

`ExecStart=/web_services/flask_api/flask_api/bin/gunicorn --workers=4 --bind=localhost:8000 --log-level=error web_service:app`

to

`ExecStart=/web_services/flask_api/flask_api/bin/gunicorn --workers=4 --bind=localhost:8000 --log-level=error app:app`